# The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(System.Windows.UIElement)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to add this method to the grid and place it in a cell in the grid. Im guessing the error is im getting is because I cant convert:  `private void BarCode()` into the `System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection` any ideas on how can I get around this?

```
myGrid.Children.Add(BarCode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `BarCode()` method needs to return `UIElement`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your `BarCode` function like this

```
private UIElement BarCode()
{
    Image myBarCode = new Image();
    myBarCode.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("bitmap.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    return myBarCode;
}
```